# DDD how to validate whole aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have AggregateEntity

```
class AggregateEntity {

   private Enum enitityStatus;

   private EntityA entityA;
   private EntityB entityB;
   private EntityC entityC;
   //.. more here
    
   public final void assertThatPolicyIsFulfilled(AgregatePolicy policy) {

      List<Violation> result = policy.checkEntityA(entityA) 
                .checkEntityB(entityB) 
                .checkEntityC(entityC)
                //...more here
                .getResult()

      if(result.size > 0 ) throw new Exception(result);
 
   }
}


class AgregatePolicyWorkComplited implements AgregatePolicy {

     private EnityAPolicy entityApolicy
     //... more policies here

     Set<Violations> checkEntityA(EntityA arg) {
         // null check here
         return arg.validate(entityApolicy)
     }

     //more check methods here

}
```

requirements:

I need to test my whole aggregate against different policies. Some of them can be more restricted then others. Example: for `WORK_IN_PROGRESS` only `EntityA` should be not null and only one field `EntityA.user` need to be set. For `WORK_COMPLITED` all fields in all entities need to be set. I need to have way to pass these different policies not only to aggregate but also in entities.

This approach has few disadvantages:

- assertThatPolicyIsFulfilled is very inflexible. Each policy is used same way and need to implement methods, even if they implementation will be "do nothing".
- I need to use final to ensure Liskov substitution
- Change in interface will force changes in many classes even if they mostly have "do nothing" implementation. It breaks I from SOLID.

How I can validate whole aggregate with better way?

Comment: Any reason you can’t have a collection of checkable entities?

Comment: What are the disadvantages you perceive and want to avoid?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau - updated

Comment: @candied_orange I don't get this, I need more clarification.

Comment: Imagine the entities all had a `check()` function and supported a `checkable` interface. Now `policy` isn't something that breaks every time you add a new entity. Now the entities know how to check themselves.

Comment: if `check()` takes no args I can't test entity against different business rules. For example `MyEntity` with `status=WORK_IN_PROGRESS` will fulfill less restrictive policy but will not fulfill `WorkComplitedPolicy`

Comment: `entityA.check()` certainly can.

Comment: could you post your proposition as an answer with pseudo code example?

Comment: No. Because I'm still asking you if it would work. I'm not familiar enough with your requirements to judge this on my own. I had been thinking constructor validation might solve your problem but then I saw this `WORK_IN_PROGRESS` code. It indicates the check must happen sometime after creation.

Comment: requirements: I need to test my whole aggregate against different policies. Some of them can be more restricted then others. Example: for `WORK_IN_PROGRESS` only `EntityA` should be not null and only one field  `EntityA.user` need to be set. For `WORK_COMPLITED` all fields in all entities need to be set. I need to have way to pass these different policies not only to aggregate but also in entities. Right now inside method `checkEntityC(arg)` I do: `arg.validate(entityCPolicy)` and collect result. `entityCPolicy` is field of  `Policy`

Comment: I try to understand how policy for `entityA.check()` can be changed?

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with @candied_orange.  It would be immensely useful if the entities could check themselves.  If you need to pass a context object to them of some kind, then do so, but I'm inclined to think that dependencies between entities requires another "validator" object of some kind.

Comment: Consider editing your question to include these requirements. People shouldn't have to read through this noise to find them.

Comment: I need more than just your requirements. I need to know how those requirements came to be. And I'll tell you why: there is no way to improve upon this system in its current form. That is, _by design_ you will have to enumerate all of the different combinations of `Entity`, `checkEntity`, and `validate` for each `Policy`. This cannot be changed because you are _not_ repeating yourself. You have an arbitrary set of rules (`Policy`) that needs to evaluate an arbitrary piece of data (`Entity`). This can't be done in a type-safe way without using interfaces. But that is likely of little use.

Comment: "Change in interface will force changes in many classes even if they mostly have "do nothing" implementation. It breaks I from SOLID" - not quite; SOLID needs to be applied strategically. IF the interface changes frequently, then it breaks from SOLID; however, if the interface is relatively stable, and you need to add new policies, then it's fine. So, one question to ask yourself is, do you have a finite set of policies, or do you expect to expand them? If the interface is stable, you can have AgregatePolicy implement default "do nothing" behavior for all the checks, and inherit that.

Comment: If the interface is not stable (which in the current design means that the number of sub-entities is expected to fluctuate), then you need to organize the validation logic around some other abstraction. Entities being able to check themselves might be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve much of this by creating an immutable work object only when you know what to stuff in it.

> for WORK_IN_PROGRESS only EntityA should be not null and only one field EntityA.user need to be set.

```
class EntityA implements Checkable {
    
    User user;
    EntityA (User user) { this.user = user; }

    List<WorkA> completedWork = new ArrayList<>();
    public void addWork(WorkA workA){ completedWork.add(workA); }
    public boolean check() { return completedWork.size() > 0; }
}
```

A collection of 1 might seem weird but this lets you avoid evil nulls and null checks. Check out the maybe monad if you want to get fancy.

> For WORK_COMPLITED all fields in all entities need to be set.

```
// Immutable data class (no setters thank you)
class WorkA {
    Field1 field1;
    Field2 field2;
    
    WorkA(Field1 field1, Field2 field2){
        this.field1 = field1;
        this.field2 = field2;
        //Whatever validation logic you need when work is completed
    }
    
    //getters if you really can't move the methods that need this data here
}
```

Now you know work is done because a `Work` object exists. `EntityA` either has one or it doesn't. You can add code to limit it to one `Work` object at a time if that's important. Done this way the 'policy' is baked into construction and validation.